# Wrong month displayed in airDatepickerInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I try to use airDatepickerInput in a shiny-app to define a date-range with years-and months only. Everything works fine but in the input box the choosen format is displayed as "2020-00" instead of "2020-01" when i choose January as the starting month for instance.

Here is my code:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    mainPanel(
          airDatepickerInput("plot_input_daterange",
                             label = "Please choose:",
                             range = TRUE,
                             value = c("2021-10", format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m")),
                             clearButton = TRUE,
                             maxDate = format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m"),
                             minDate = "2021-10-01",
                             view = "months", 
                             minView = "months", 
                             dateFormat = "yyyy-mm",
                             language= "en",
                             addon = "none")
         

      )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a capital "M": `dateFormat = "yyyy-MM"`

Please find the related docs [here](https://air-datepicker.com/docs?scrollTo=dateFormat).

---

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test"),
  mainPanel(
    airDatepickerInput("plot_input_daterange",
                       label = "Please choose:",
                       range = TRUE,
                       value = c("2021-10", format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m")),
                       clearButton = TRUE,
                       maxDate = format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m"),
                       minDate = "2021-10-01",
                       view = "months", 
                       minView = "months", 
                       dateFormat = "yyyy-MM",
                       language= "en",
                       addon = "none")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```